# How to detect a floating point number using a regular expression

Tags: regex, floating-point

What is a good regular expression for handling a floating point number (i.e. like Java's Float)

The answer must match against the following targets:

```
 1) 1.  
 2) .2   
 3) 3.14  
 4) 5e6  
 5) 5e-6  
 6) 5E+6  
 7) 7.e8  
 8) 9.0E-10  
 9) .11e12
```

In summary, it should

- ignore preceding signs
- require the first character to the left of the decimal point to be non-zero
- allow 0 or more digits on either side of the decimal point
- permit a number without a decimal point
- allow scientific notation
- allow capital or lowercase 'e'
- allow positive or negative exponents

For those who are wondering, yes this is a homework problem.  We received this as an assignment in my graduate CS class on compilers. I've already turned in my answer for the class and will post it as an answer to this question.

[Epilogue]
My solution didn't get full credit because it didn't handle more than 1 digit to the left of the decimal.  The assignment did mention handling Java floats even though none of the examples had more than 1 digit to the left of the decimal.  I'll post the accepted answer in it's own post.

Comment: I personally would write a bunch of unit tests ...

Comment: These are very strange requirements. Such an expression will not match "0.5".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[This is the answer from the professor]

Define:

N = [1-9]
D = 0 | N
E = [eE] [+-]? D+
L = 0 | ( N D* )

Then floating point numbers can be matched with:

( ( L . D* | . D+ ) E? ) | ( L E )

It was also acceptable to use D+ rather than L, and to prepend [+-]?.

A common mistake was to write D* . D*, but this can match just '.'.

[Edit]
Someone asked about a leading sign; I should have asked him why it was excluded but never got the chance. Since this was part of the lecture on grammars, my guess is that either it made the problem easier (not likely) or there is a small detail in parsing where you divide the problem set such that the floating point value, regardless of sign, is the focus (possible).

If you are parsing through an expression, e.g.

> -5.04e-10 + 3.14159E10

the sign of the floating point value is part of the operation to be applied to the value and not an attribute of the number itself. In other words,

> subtract (5.04e-10)
>   add (3.14159E10)

to form the result of the expression.  While I'm sure mathematicians may argue the point, remember this was from a lecture on parsing.

Comment: What about Infinity and NaN?

Comment: Since the exercise was about parsing a language, I would venture that the grammar would need to define tokens that represent those concepts assuming they are allowed as input.

Answer (score 26):

Just make both the decimal dot and the E-then-exponent part optional:

```
[1-9][0-9]*\.?[0-9]*([Ee][+-]?[0-9]+)?
```

I don't see why you don't want a leading `[+-]?` to capture a possible sign too, but, whatever!-)

**Edit**: there might in fact be no digits left of the decimal point (in which case I imagine there *must* be the decimal point *and* 1+ digits after it!), so a vertical-bar (alternative) is clearly needed:

```
(([1-9][0-9]*\.?[0-9]*)|(\.[0-9]+))([Ee][+-]?[0-9]+)?
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't match anything of the form `.x` or `0.x`.

Comment: @Alex: He might not want to capture the sign in case it's part of an expression, as in "5-2.5". That's expected if you're tokenizing things, as you would be when writing a compiler.

Comment: You might want to note the explicit presence of `.2` in the list of examples that need to be matched, though. I guess this is somewhere a clear spec is required. :/

Comment: Aha, good point.  Then a vertical bar is definitely needed to express the fact that there might be no digits to the left of the decimal point, but, if there are, then the first one must be non-zero.  Let me edit the A to show this.

Comment: And btw, @Anon, tx and +1 for pointing out this inconsistency in the question as expressed (an example contradicting a rule;-).

Comment: @Alex: I asked about the preceeding sign and was told not to bother with it for this assignment.  It'd be simple enough to prepend [-+]? though.

Comment: What about #4 where there is no decimal?  It's the reason I have a third alternative in my answer but I'm interested in other ways to achieve the same result.

Comment: Ah yes - I *said* the period had to be optional, made it optional in the first RE, but the question mark slipped away as I wrote the second one;-).  Editing the A to fix!

Comment: This pattern won't match "0" or "0.7". Here's my revision: `-?(0(\.\d*)?|([1-9]\d*\.?\d*)|(\.\d+))([Ee][+-]?\d+)?`

Answer (score 5):

http://www.regular-expressions.info/floatingpoint.html

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I turned in.

```
(([1-9]+\.[0-9]*)|([1-9]*\.[0-9]+)|([1-9]+))([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?
```

To make it easier to discuss, I'll label the sections

```
( ([1-9]+ \. [0-9]* ) | ( [1-9]* \. [0-9]+ ) | ([1-9]+))  ( [eE] [-+]? [0-9]+ )?     
--------------------------------------------------------  ----------------------    
                           A                                       B
```

A: matches everything up to the 'e/E'
B: matches the scientific notation

Breaking down A we get three parts

```
 ( ([1-9]+ \. [0-9]* ) | ( [1-9]* \. [0-9]+ ) | ([1-9]+) )
   ----------1----------   ---------2----------   ---3----
```

Part 1: Allows 1 or more digits from 1-9, decimal, 0 or more digits after the decimal (target 1)
Part 2: Allows 0 or more digits from 1-9, decimal, 1 or more digits after the decimal (target 2)
Part 3: Allows 1 or more digits from 1-9 with no decimal (see #4 in target list)

---

Breaking down B we get 4 basic parts

```
 ( [eE] [-+]? [0-9]+  )?   
   ..--1- --2-- --3--- -4- ..
```

Part 1: requires either upper or lowercase 'e' for scientific notation  (e.g. targets 8 & 9)
Part 2: allows an optional positive or negative sign for the exponent  (e.g. targets 4, 5, & 6)
Part 3: allows 1 or more digits for the exponent (target 8)
Part 4: allows the scientific notation to be optional as a group (target 3)

Comment: Your first part (1) of (A) does not allow `10.`.

Comment: Part (1) of (A) should probably be `([1-9][0-9]*\.[0-9]*)`. A similar change is needed to part (3).

Comment: @tur1ng: true but blame the the test input! 8-)

Comment: @tur1ng, it turns out my solution was marked down for exactly that reason. The prof did admit that sample input wasn't complete but said those were only examples and not the entire domain of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

@Kelly S. French, this regular expression matches all your test cases.

```
^[+-]?(\d+\.\d+|\d+\.|\.\d+|\d+)([eE][+-]?\d+)?$
```

Source: [perldoc perlretut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Building-a-regexp)

Comment: This doesn't work for '0' (zero).

Answer (score 1):

```
'([-+])?\d*(\.)?\d+(([eE]([-+])?)?\d+)?'
```

That's the regular expression I have arrived at when trying to solve this kind of task in Matlab. Actually, it won't correctly detect numbers like (1.) but some additional changes may solve the problem... well, maybe the following would fix that:

```
'([-+])?(\d+(\.)?\d*|\d*(\.)?\d+)(([eE]([-+])?)?\d+)?'
```

Comment: This doesn't work for '0' (zero).

Answer (score 1):

@Kelly S. French: the sign is missing because in a parser it would get added by the unary minus (negation) expression, therefore it is not neccessary to be detected as part of a float.