# Regular expression does not match a number with e+ or e-

Tags: regex, numbers

I want to match any number with a regular expression. I have written this expression (added whitespace for readability):

```
( ([0-9]+(\.[0-9]*)?) | (\.[0-9]+) )( (e|E)(\+|\-)[0-9](\.[0-9])? )?
```

This would need to match any number in one of the following forms:

- `12345`
- `12.345`
- `.12345`
- `12345.`
- `12e-345` or `12E-345`
- `12e+345` or `12E+345`

It matches the first four notations, but the last four (those with e- and e+) don't. What have I done wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Adding whitespace for readability also hides whitespace that might have been breaking things.

Comment: @Wooble there is no whitespace in the actual expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Focus on that part of the expression:

```
(e|E)(\+|\-)[0-9](\.[0-9])?
```

You're only allowing *one* digit after `e|E`, optionally followed by a `.` *and one* other digit.

Comment: This is indeed the problem. Didn't notice it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is the final slashdot '\.'.

Also, there is no * so it will only allow one or two digits in the exponent.

```
(\.[0-9])? )?
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for 1 digit after the [eE]. Change the ? to a +

```
( ([0-9]+(\.[0-9]*)?) | (\.[0-9]+) )( (e|E)(\+|\-)[0-9]+(\.[0-9])+ )?
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the regex matches numbers of the form `12.34e+4.5`. The `[0-9](\.[0-9])?` part should be changed to `[0-9]+`.

```
( ([0-9]+(\.[0-9]*)?) | (\.[0-9]+) )( (e|E)(\+|\-)[0-9]+ )?
```

See also [How to detect a floating point number using a regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293780/how-to-detect-a-floating-point-number-using-a-regular-expression).

Answer (score 0):

Use this: `\d+[eE][+-]\d+|\d+\.?\d*|\.\d+`