# Number Regular Expression Help

Tags: regex

I am learning regular expressions and I am trying to create one that will validation either a whole number or a decimal.

I have created this regular expression:

```
^(\d+)|([\d+][\.{1}][\d+])$
```

It almost works, but it says a number like:

```
12. 
12..
12..67
```

are matches.

I thought

```
([\d+][\.{1}][\d+])
```

meant it had to have one or more numbers, followed by a dot (and only one), followed by one or more numbers.

Can someone explain what I am doing wrong?

As a learning process I'm interested in what I am doing wrong rather than what is another way of doing it. I tried following the syntax examples but I have missed something.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect a floating point number using a regular expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293780/how-to-detect-a-floating-point-number-using-a-regular-expression)

Comment: I deleted my answer because it was not ok! but you can check this page  http://regexlib.com/DisplayPatterns.aspx?cattabindex=2&categoryId=3&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are wrong

```
([\d+][\.{1}][\d+])
```

with the square brackets are you creating character classes. that means

`[\d+]` does mean match a digit or a `+` once.

`[\.{1}]` does mean match a `.` or a `{` or a `1` or a `}`

To get the behaviour you expect remove the square brackets

```
(\d+\.{1}\d+)
```

This will match at least one digit, a `.` followed by one or more digits

The other problem here is the `^` belongs only to the first part of your expression and the `$` belong only to the last part of your alternation. So you should put brackets around the complete alternation

```
^((\d+)|(\d+\.{1}\d+))$
```

If you don't need the match in a capturing group you can remove the brackets around the single alternatives

```
^(\d+|\d+\.{1}\d+)$
```

As last point as Jens noted

`{1}` is redundant `\.{1}` is the same than `\.`

Then we are at

```
^(\d+|\d+\.\d+)$
```

Comment: Note that `{1}` is redundant.

Comment: @Jens yes are right I am still thinking about the other stuff in this expression

Comment: @stema Thank you for the comprehensive explanation! That was exactly what I was looking for. It's one thing knowing what I've done is wrong, but understanding why it is wrong is the key to learning how to do it right next time!

Answer (score 0):

You can try with:

```
^(\d+(\.\d+)?)$
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is nearly there, you just need to remove the square brackets -

```
^(\d+)|(\d+\.{1}\d+)$
```

Should work for what you want.