# Javascript: Regular expression to allow negative and positive floating point numbers?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression to match both positive and negative floating points of any length of characters. I tried this

```
/^-|[0-9\ ]+$/
```

However this is still wrong because for example it would match "46.0" and "-46.0" but will also match "4-6.0" which I don't want.

At the moment i'm using this

```
/^-|[0-9][0-9\ ]+$/
```

This fixes the first problem but this will match something like "-4g" and that is also incorrect.

What expression can I use to match negative and positive floating points?

Comment: I'm skeptical SO would have been faster than a search.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect a floating point number using a regular expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293780/how-to-detect-a-floating-point-number-using-a-regular-expression)

Comment: This comes up first searching for "regex for negative float"

Answer (score 7):

Why not the following?

```
parseFloat(x) === x
```

If you really want a regex, there are [entire pages on the internet](http://www.regular-expressions.info/floatingpoint.html) dedicated to this task. Their conclusion:

```
/^[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+$/
```

or

```
/^[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?$/
```

if you want to allow exponential notation.

Comment: doesn't allow for "42." which is a perfectly valid JS number. also, 42.e3 isn't matched like it should be.

Answer (score -1):

```
/^[-+]?[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?(?:[eE][-+][0-9]+)?$/
```

This also allows for an exponent part. If you don't want that, just use

```
/^[-+]?[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?$/
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Well mine is bit lesser, optional you can remove `{1,3}` limits to minimum 1 and max 3 numbers part and replace that with `+` to make no limit on numbers.

```js
/^[\-]?\d{1,3}\.\d$/
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this...

I am sure, it's work in javascript.

var pattern = new RegExp("^-?[0-9.]*$");

if (pattern.test(valueToValidate))
{

```
   return true;
```

}
else
 {

```
 return false;
```

}

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.  In particular, does it accept `3.4.5`?  (It shouldn't)  How about the empty string?