# Rails 5 Validation with Regular expresion format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

I want to validate a number field with regular expression -

like

```
REGULAR_EXPRESSION_VALUE = ?
validates :current, allow_blank: true, format: {with: REGULAR_EXPRESSION_VALUE}
```

which excepts postive or negative number and also floating point numbers

Examples

10 (Except)

10.15 (Except)

-10 (Except)

-10.15 (Except)

Test (Not Except)

Comment: why aren't you using numericality builtin validation ? http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#numericality

Comment: I need negative or positive values as input and not string. numaricality allows only positive or only negative not both. So I need to validate with regex @Manishh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ravi's answer has good regex. Here it is for your code

```
/\A[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+\z/
```

Rails prefers to use \A or \z instead of ^ or $

[This is reason why](https://stackoverflow.com/a/577675/8929392)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following regex to validate number or not.
I am using java to write code, you can convert accordingly.

```
public static Boolean isNumber(String item) {
            String pattern = "^-?[0-9]\\d*(\\.\\d+)?$";
            return item.matches(pattern);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this Answer ([regular expression-to allow negative and positive floating point num](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8025060/javascript-regular-expression-to-allow-negative-and-positive-floating-point-num?)), you can use this regex:

`/^[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+$/`

And i suggest you to read some docs: https://www.regular-expressions.info/floatingpoint.html

I suppose you need to use a string instead of float type right?
If you can use a numeric format in your database, you can use: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#numericality