# RegExp to accept positive and negative numbers

Tags: javascript, regex, angular

I trying to accept positive and negative no in angular reactive form validation

```
 [Validators.required, Validators.pattern("^-?[0-9]d*(.d+)?$")]
```

It only accept one no after it gives me an error

Comment: Would you [try](https://regex101.com/r/JPDIPL/1) out `^\-?\d+(\.\d+)?$`?

Comment: ^\-?\d+(\.\d+)?$ not working

Answer (score 3):

You may use

```
[Validators.required, Validators.pattern("-?\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?")]
```

Or,

```
[Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/^-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?$/)]
```

**NOTES**:

- If you define the regex with a string literal, `"..."`, remember that `^` and `$` are appended by angular automatically, you do not need to specify them explicitly AND you need to double escape backslashes to define regex escape sequences, like `\d`, `\w`, `\b`, `\W`, etc.
- If you define the regex using a regex literal notation, `/.../`, you need to add `^` and `$` to ensure a full string match, and you need to use single backslashes to define regex escapes.

The `^-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?$` regex is rather basic, you may find more at [Regular expression for floating point numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12643009) and [Javascript: Regular expression to allow negative and positive floating point numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8025060).

Answer (score 0):

check [this](https://www.regextester.com/) works for Integers or decimal numbers with or without the exponential form

```html
^[+-]?([0-9]*\.?[0-9]+|[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*)([eE][+-]?[0-9]+)?$
```

for more regex try this [website](https://regexlib.com/)