# comparing input values in java

Tags: java

I'm trying to compare input values. Here's a sample of what I want to say.

```
           if(text.input != float)
           {
              //code to calculate
           }
```

I don't want to allow values other than numbers being entered. Is this correct?

Comment: Not its not correct way ..will not work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should do something like

```
try {
  float value = Float.valueOf(text.input);
  // Do something with value - it's OK.
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
  // text.input is not a float, handle appropriately...
}
```

Comment: What is _user-define_? `text.input` should obviously be a `java.lang.String`.

Answer (score 0):

Using a try/catch block to implement the logic will "work", but I'm not sure that it's the more efficient thing to do.

If the text value is actually a float all but a small percentage of the time, so non-floats truly are an exceptional situation, then I'd agree with the try/catch arrangement.

If non-floats are a more substantial fraction of the input, I'd say you're better off using a regular expression to check for valid floats rather than throwing an exception.

Comment: Your statement is generally correct (exceptions should be saved for handling of _exceptional_ situations), but from my experience, this is an exception itself :), due to its wide use. `Float.valueOf()` can also parse the engineering notation and some other stuff, by the way.

Comment: Fair enough.  The OP (and everyone else) ought to be aware of the tradeoff.  A regular expression could do the same without the exception.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293780/how-to-detect-a-floating-point-number-using-a-regular-expression