# Extracting a Floating point exponential formatted number from a text file

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to extract a floating point exponential number from a number of `.txt` files that is searched for using a phrase and then extracted. For example I have a `.txt` file that looks like this.

```
FEA Results:
Tip rotation (deg) =, 7.107927E-18
Tip displacement =, 3.997556E-07
```

And I'm extracting the tip rotation data using the following script:

```
regexp = re.compile(r'Tip rotation .*?([0-9.-]+)')
    with open(fileName) as f:
        for line in f:
            match = regexp.match(line)
            if match:
                rotations.append(float((match.group(1))))
```

The problem is it only returns the first part of the floating point exponential (i.e. `7.107927` instead of `7.107927E-18`).  Any idea on how I could correct it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex has this:

```
([0-9.-]+)
```

It's missing the E - add that in the brackets (at the front or the back, doesn't matter).  Also, you may need to move the minus sign to the front, so it isn't interpreted as a range.  Like this:

```
([-0-9.E]+)
```

Comment: Right on the money you legend! Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression doesn't allow for `E-18`. Specifically, `E` isn't mentioned.

See this question for better regexps: [How to detect a floating point number using a regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293780/how-to-detect-a-floating-point-number-using-a-regular-expression)