# Python: Strip Everything but Numbers

Tags: python, string, numeric, strip

I have to extract a number (a measured time value) from each of several strings. How could I do this elegantly? All numbers are positive and have a maximum of two decimal places. (E.g.: 2.3/ 40.09/ 101.4 - no numbers in E notation). The code I am looking for should do something like the following pseudocode:

```
>>> "It took 2.3 seconds".strip(everything but ".1234567890")
2.3
```

Comment: define "number". `-2.3`? `+4.5e-127`? `0xcafebabe`?

Comment: In this special case only positive numbers with maximum 2 digits are possible, since the time example is close to the real task: Only positive time values.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Instead of strip, select for the numbers with a regular expression:

```
import re

numbers = re.compile(r'\d+(?:\.\d+)?')
numbers.findall("It took 2.3 seconds")
```

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> numbers = re.compile(r'\d+(?:\.\d+)?')
>>> numbers.findall("It took 2.3 seconds")
['2.3']
```

This returns a list of all matches; this lets you find multiple numbers in a string too:

```
>>> numbers.findall("It took between 2.3 and 42.31 seconds")
['2.3', '42.31']
```

Comment: There are some complicated ones here that deal with negative numbers and scientific notation - those may be out of scope for the OP. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293780/how-to-detect-a-floating-point-number-using-a-regular-expression

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper: Since the OP specifically wanted to strip everything but `.0123456789` I kept it simple.

Answer (score 9):

If all you want to do is remove all characters that aren't in another string, I'd suggest something like the following:

```
>>> to_filter = "It took 2.3 seconds"
>>> "".join(_ for _ in to_filter if _ in ".1234567890")
'2.3'
```

It's an *extremely* naive way to extract numbers, however. You should use the answer by Martijn Pieters if you want more than just a simple character filter like you asked for.