# 400 : Invalid value 'ga:pagePath=' for filters parameter

Tags: google-analytics

Using the google analytics [query explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/), I would like to limit the output of the following data:

**Example data**

```
ga:pagePath
/100464.html
/108659.html?promid=1552
```

**Aim**
only get the numbers from pagepath, so:

```
ga:pagePath
100464
108659
```

**Tried**
The following filter fails:

```
ga:pagePath=/....
```

With following error message:

```
400 : Invalid value 'ga:pagePath=/....' for filters parameter.
```

**Solution**
Thanks to Eike Pierstorff -> this is not filtering. This is programming logic.
E.g. a filter is used to narrow down the data but NOT control/ change how the output is returned. 
To only get the numbers, use a regex in your programming code. An example on how to do so is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19594172/python-strip-everything-but-numbers).

Comment: Either I misunderstand your post or you misunderstand how filtering works. Filters limit the results to the given criteria, they do not filter the individual fields in the results. If you want to remove the file extensions from the results urls you have to download the results as a spreadsheets and format the rows accordingly. Plus, see DalmTos answer regarding the difference between "=" and "==".

Comment: @EikePierstorff, I was wrong. I mixed up filtering with output. I updated the question with a solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

its == not =

[Filter documentation link](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#filters)

> == (Equals) %3D%3D Return results where the time on the page is exactly ten seconds: filters=ga:timeOnPage%3D%3D10

so try

```
ga:pagePath==/
ga:pagePath==/?attachment_id=106
```

for fun: returns everything with a ?

```
ga:pagePath=@?
```