# C# - modify doubles in string

Tags: c#, double

I want to edit the double values that are parts in strings with large varition of type:

"1/(2.342/x)"

"x^3.45"

"123*x"

and so on.

Any good example on how I can only modify them? Be cause I want to be able to change them for a new random double. E.g

"1/(2.342/x)"  ---> "1/(23.2/x)"

"x^3.45" ---> "x^0.2"

"123*x" ---"3.23*x"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to that, to extract floating values by using regex and convert them via float/decimal/double or whatever data type you need.

After your modification, you can replace your string using same regex again.

```
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"[1-9][0-9]*\.?[0-9]*([Ee][+-]?[0-9]+)?");
        string testString ="1/(2.342/x) * x^3.45";
        MatchCollection collection = regex.Matches(testString);
        foreach(Match item in collection)
        {
            double extract =Convert.ToDouble(item.Value);
            //change your decimal here...
            testString = testString.Replace(item.Value, extract.ToString());
        }
```

regex credits to : https://stackoverflow.com/a/2293793/2084262